# Perl-remove string between table tags

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl and am trying to remove tables from HTML files under some conditions.

Here is an example. I want to remove the string between table tags if the string does not contain the string xyz. But the code does not work, it does not remove the first table. How should I revise the codes to make it work? Thank you very much!!

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $data = <<TEXT;

<table>
(aaa)
</table>

<table>
xyz
</table>

TEXT

my @find=();
@find=$data =~ m/<TABLE[^>]*>(.*?)<\/TABLE>/imosg;

foreach (@find) {
if ($_!~ m/xyz/imosg){$data =~ s/$_//;}
}

print "$data\n","*" x 40, "\n" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@find` contains the string `\n(aaa)\n` (where `\n` is a newline character). When you call `$data =~ s/$_//`, you are not matching because the parentheses characters in `$_` are regexp metacharacters. `$data =~ s/\n(aaa)\n//` does not match and replace the string `\n(aaa)\n`; it matches the string `\naaa\n` and returns the string `aaa` as a capture group (say, in the special variable `$1`).

Perl provides a couple of mechanisms to match a literal string in a regular expression. One is to wrap the string in `\Q` and (sometimes optional) `\E` tags:

```
$data =~ s/\Q$_\E//;           # match literal contents of $_
```

A second way is to use the [`quotemeta`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#quotemeta) function prior to applying the regular expression.

```
my $q = quotemeta($_);
$data =~ s/$q//;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can get away with regexes for quick-and-dirty manipulation of HTML, you might like to consider using an HTML parser as a less error-prone approach.  Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use XML::LibXML;

my $html = <<'EOF';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Country</th><th>Population</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Lithuania</td><td>2,908,249</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Bermuda</td><td>61,666</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Country</th><th>Population</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Botswana</td><td>2,250,260</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Dominica</td><td>73,543</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
EOF

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html(
    string  => $html,
    recover => 1,
);

foreach my $table ($dom->findnodes('//table')) {
    my $text_content = $table->to_literal;
    if($text_content =~ /botswana/i) {
        $table->parentNode->removeChild($table);
    }
}

say $dom->toStringHTML();
```

[Some more examples](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/html.html).

Comment: The regexp vs parsing choice also depends on the quality of the HTML. Dirty input sometimes require dirty methods (regexp).

Comment: To be fair, LibXML's HTML parsing is very good at dealing with poor quality HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into the HTML parsing in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Web::Query::LibXML 'wq';
my $w = wq <<'HTML';
<html><body>
<table>
(aaa)
</table>

<table>
xyz
</table>
HTML
$w->find('table:not(:contains("xyz"))')->html('');
print $w->as_html;
```

Comment: Without the <html> it doesn't work. Also with `<tr><td>xyz</td></tr>` instead of just `xyz`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data =~ s{(<table.*?>)(.*?)(</table>)}
          {
            my($one,$two,$three) = ($1,$2,$3);
            $two =~ /xyz/
            ? "$one$two$three"
            : "$one$three"
          }esig;
```

...but that wouldn't work if you have a <table> inside a <table>. Do real HTML-parsing if so.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I will look at the HTML parsing using Perl.